# Magento 2: Composer update / install is no longer copying magento2-base structure

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer

I've got this strange problem I ran into only since recently.

Usually, when I got a new or existing project and I run `composer install` or `composer update`, composer will automatically copy (map) the contents of `magento2-base` to my project root. So `magento2-base/lib` gets copied to `/lib` and `magento2-base/app/bootstrap.php` gets copied to `/app/bootstrap.php` and so on...

But for some reason composer is not doing this anymore. Does anyone has any clue on how this can happen? I'm experiencing this issue all of a sudden since last Friday.

Answer (score 8):

Found it! Turned out in a previous commit I accidentally removed the following from my `composer.json`-file:

```
"extra": {
  "magento-force": "override"
}
```

Turns out that Magento uses this variable to determine if mapped folders in vendor modules' `composer.json` files are allowed to be copied (if they don't already exist).